# 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting - Not modifying the scope in any way

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am learning Meteor using angular and I am a bit stumped with this error.

In my folder structure:

```
client
|_ index.html
|_ main.html
|_ main.js
```

main.html contains the template I want to show on the page. This is a simple-as-can-be template.

```
<div ng-controller="ClassListCtrl">
    test away big boy! 
</div>
```

in main.js I have the module set up:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';

angular.module('rpgGame', [
    angularMeteor
]).controller('ClassListCtrl', function($scope){
    'ngInject';
});
```

and in index.html - I load the app, switch on `ng-strict-di` and include main.html as the source of a div using the `ng-include` directive:

```
<body ng-app="rpgGame" ng-strict-di="">
    <div ng-include src="'client/main.html'"></div>
</body>
```

however, as I mentioned in the title, I get

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Now - I haven't modified the scope in any way, thus I cannot see why angular will call digest updates - let alone that I haven't even iterated through a collection nor changed any collections. Why would this error be thrown?

from my console:

```
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: constantWatch","newVal":"client/main.html"}],[{"msg":"fn: constantWatch","newVal":"client/main.html"}],[{"msg":"fn: constantWatch","newVal":"client/main.html"}],[{"msg":"fn: constantWatch","newVal":"client/main.html"}],[{"msg":"fn: constantWatch","newVal":"client/main.html"}]]
```

Comment: it must be with the library not with your code, it seems fine. whats this doing **ng-strict-di=""** ?

Comment: ng-strict-di directive is in place incase there is a minification problem. If there is a minification problem, it would be detected in development phase and and not only in production.

see www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/dynamic-template

Comment: I followed their instructions to the tee - but also renamed my controllers/collections ... it didn't worked. I dumbed it down to the version asked in the question - still throws the error there. Restarted meteor. Even Reinstalled all my packages

Comment: is your code on git?

Comment: no - this is something I picked up yesterday. it's local-only now

Comment: ok i'm gonna try it.

Comment: by googling "angularMeteor digest aborting" i see many posts on stackoverflow about infinite digest while using angularMeteor but none out of the 3 i checked had a valid answer. Apparently it's a probem with the library. Try removing it from your dependencies just to test this theory

Comment: after digging a bit it seems to be something with library not your code. if you print angularMeteor you can see it's only string to the whole module.

Comment: my god. seems you are right. post it as an answer and I will tick it

Comment: Just did it. I will digg more to find why it's happening.

Comment: How are you using your app? have you installed meteor?

Comment: I can see on github it build fail. I'm opning an issue let them see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your code it's the library. If you print angularMeteor you can see its not an module.

Comment: Just remember to edit your answer and include any other information you dig up :) I have something to show my superiors - as in why the code actually broke

Comment: Sure I will do it.